# How exactly DMA offloads processor/controller?

Tags: memory-management, microcontroller, dma, microprocessors

I know DMA acts as a channel where the CPU gets bypassed while data is transferred between Memory/ Peripheral,and in the mean-time CPU can execute useful operations..

But my question is ...

If the DMA transfer is going-on the DATA-BUS will be acquired by the DMA controller, So if the CPU needs to fetch/retrieve data for any operation it needs the access to data bus where it will be used by the DMA data transfer. So how exactly we can say that DMA offloaded the CPU?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Sure, they may share a bus, but compare DMA to no DMA:

DMA:

Periph == Bus ==> RAM

No DMA:

Periph == Bus ==> CPU == Bus ==> RAM

Without DMA, most peripherals have one or more registers which have to be actively read by the CPU for each data unit (often 1 or 4 bytes). With DMA, the device can write directly to RAM without the CPU doing a thing. There is indeed still contention for the bus, but not every operation the CPU does needs the bus. Also, some peripherals send or receive data more slowly than the bus speed, which means the DMA operation doesn't fill the bus, leaving room for the CPU use it also.

Comment: In microcontrollers such as STM32 they have an extra RAM called CCRAM which is coupled to the CPU to which the MCU doesn't need the BUS. Does Microprocessors has this kind of RAM , How they handle such situations ?

Comment: I don't know. You'd have to read the datasheet for your specific chip. I have not ever worked closely enough with such a controller to have ever heard of CCRAM before.